# PHP, html, image file permissions?

Tags: php

In a typical PHP application what should the file permissions of .php, .html and image files be? I'm using PHP5 with Apache on a Linux box.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no "typical" situation imo.

In our production systems our file permissions for the entire DocumentRoot are:

-rw-rw-r-- 186 deploy deploy    677 Nov 17 11:32 template.php

They are owned by the deploy user, as that's the user we use to deploy our application in our production environment. They are group writable so that others in the deploy group (sysadmins, developers) can modify them if need be. In a shared system you would probably not have 0664 because you wouldn't want other people reading your files, and you'd probably use 0660 or 0640.

Answer (score -2):

html and images should be readonly to the to web server's user

php should be read & execute

Comment: PHP does not need to be executable.

Comment: u sure? i remember having "forbiden" problems without that

Comment: I am sure about that! Unless you use it as a shell script!